# Guard throws error attempting to redirect to another page

Tags: angular

I am trying to have a AuthGuard redirect user to Unauthorized page if they are loggedin.
However it fails every time and i can't figure out why.

Error message:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'unauthorized'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'unauthorized'
```

app.component.html

```
<router-outlet *ngIf="isAuthenticated()"></router-outlet>
<router-outlet *ngIf="!isAuthenticated()" name="public"></router-outlet>
```

auth.guard.ts

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private router: Router, private authServ: AuthService ) { }

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
    return this.checkUser(route, state);
  }

  private checkUser(route: any, state: any): boolean {
    console.log('AuthorizationGuard is hit');

    if(!this.authServ.isAuthorized()) {
            this.router.navigate(['/unauthorized']);
            return false;
    } else {
            return true;
    }
  }
}
```

my app.routing.module routes defined as follows:

```
  { path: 'dashboard', component: MainDashboardComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'unauthorized', component: UnauthorizedComponent, outlet: 'public'},
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent, outlet: 'public'}
```

Any advice is appreciated.
I suspect this isssue is tied to named outlet, as when i don't use it, it doesn't appear to occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax for secondary outlet is different you need to define object is the frst parameter to link parameter of the array

Try this

```
private checkUser(route: any, state: any): boolean {
    console.log('AuthorizationGuard is hit');

    if(!this.authServ.isAuthorized()) {
            this.router.navigate([{outlets:{public:['unauthorized']}}]);
            return false;
    } else {
            return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You added the unauthorized path for outlet public so it is happening.
You can remove the outlet option from the app.routing.module.ts

```
  { path: 'unauthorized', component: UnauthorizedComponent, outlet: 'public'},
```

TO:

```
  { path: 'unauthorized', component: UnauthorizedComponent },
```

And html

```
<router-outlet *ngIf="isAuthenticated()"></router-outlet>
<router-outlet *ngIf="!isAuthenticated()" name="public"></router-outlet>
```

To

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```